# join two text file in bash that is separated by comma

Tags: join

### file 1:

```
Doe, John, phone123
Dane, Jane, phone124
```

### file 2

```
phone123, longdistance, 10mins
phone124, local, 5mins
phone124, longdistance, 6mins
```

### output

```
Doe, John phone123 longdistance 10mins
Dane, Jane phone124 local 5mins
Dane, Jane phone124 longdistance 6mins
```

So far, I have

```
join -1 1 -2 3 -o 2.1,2.2,1.1,1.2,1.3 file2.txt file1.txt > output.txt
```

it works if file 1 and 2 is separated by only space without "," but when I put the comma in the file it outputs blanks.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the delimiter with `-t,`?

Comment: i honestly have no idea how to use delimiter

Comment: i have thought about removing all comma with sed but i also dont want to change file1 and file2.txt

Comment: i tried join -t, -11 -2 3 -o...... and no luck saying not sorted

Comment: I think the issue is -1 1 and -2 3 even though they are same value one has a comma and the other does not

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is the 2-character field separator. Tools like join and sort expect the separator to be just one character:

```bsh
join -t, -13 -21 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3 \
  <(sed -E 's/, +/,/g' file1.txt | sort -t, -k3,3) \
  <(sed -E 's/, +/,/g' file2.txt | sort -t, -k1,1)
```

outputs

```
Doe,John,phone123,longdistance,10mins
Dane,Jane,phone124,local,5mins
Dane,Jane,phone124,longdistance,6mins
```

And you might want to pipe that into `| sed 's/,/, /g'` to restore the "comma space" separators.

---

Alternately, [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```bsh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = ", *"; OFS = ", "}
    NR == FNR {name[$3] = $1 OFS $2; next}
    $1 in name {print name[$1], $0}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: thank you, for now i used join, however i have seen awk around, can you give the quick downlow on difference between join and awk and when to use which one?

Comment: Learn more about `awk` [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info). awk is a complete programming language, so if you need to do more than table joins, awk can do it.  `join` is a bit fragile about the order of the  data files, so you often need to explicitly pre-process the files (as I did here). Plus, joining more than 2 files gets painful quickly.